# Trying to pick out a specific part of a string with regex

Tags: regex

I've tried and tried again to find a regex for this pattern.
I have a string like this picked from HTML source.

`<!-- TAG=Something / Something else -->`

And sometimes it's just:

`<!-- TAG=Something -->`

In both cases I want the regex to just match "Something", i.e. everything between TAG= and an optional /.

My first attempt was:

`TAG=(.*)[/]?(.*) -->`

But the first parenthesis matches everything between TAG= and --> no matter what. So what is the correct way here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
TAG=([^/]*)(?:/(.*))?-->
```

Group 1 will contain "Something".
Group 2 will contain "Something else" or null.

[Test it.](http://www.rubular.com/r/2q9jMTj2xS)

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine and in a concise way too. I tried using ^/ but for some reason the app i was using to test the regex (http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex) said that was invalid :S. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--.*?=(.*?)(-->|/)
```

It matches everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-greedy modifier `?`:

```
TAG=(.*?)[/]?.* -->
```

Also your usage of `[/]` seems unusual - you don't need a character class to write a single character. The most likely explanation for this unusual syntax is probably because you are using `/` as the regular expression delimiter, meaning that `/` is treated as a special character. In many (not all) regex dialects it is possible solve this issue by using a different delimiter, such as `#`. This prevents you from needing to escape the slashes.

Comment: He used `[/]` instead of `\/`. I don't know why they do it, but I've seen it done by other people here on SO.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: I think people use `[/]` instead of `\/` to avoid Leaning Toothpick Syndrome. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome - that's OK. However, in my opinion it is much better just to change the delimiter, if that's at all possible.

Comment: In many cases it isn't possible. Like when defining the RegEx as a literal. But you argument still stands.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Actually on Perl for example, due to the highly unusual language syntax, it is possible to change the delimiter *even when it is a literal* (not a string). However in Javascript for example it is not possible. Since the OP hasn't specified which language he is using I tried to avoid making any sweeping assumptions.